# mpiexec error on HPC: execvp error on file srun (No such file or directory)

Tags: python-3.x, containers, mpi, hpc

On the HPC, I first test

`apptainer exec my_container bash -c "activate environment; python3 script.py"`

It worked well.

Then it also works well if I use terminal interactively like:

```
apptainer shell my_container
activate environment
mpiexec -n 5 python3 script.py
```

But, if I tried to write a slurm script with

`apptainer exec my_container bash -c "activate environment;mpiexec -n 5  python3 script.py"`

I got the following message:
[mpiexec@acn89] HYDU_create_process (lib/utils/launch.c:73): execvp error on file srun (No such file or directory)

Any helps are greatly appreciated.

Comment: than can work on a single node, but will fail in a multi node environment since `mpiexec` in the container cannot find `srun` (SLURM remote launcher) and on (at least) the other nodes, `script.py` will not run inside any container. A typical job would do `srun apptainer exec my_container bash -c "activate environment; python3 script.py". I can use `mpiexec` instead of `srun` if `mpiexec` on the host match the MPI library in your container.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks for the suggestion. May I know some tips to check whether the mpiexec on the host match the MPI library in container? If it does not match, do I need to rebuild MPI library in container? Thank you

Comment: my recommendation is to use `srun`. If not, `mpirun --version` on both host and container should match (and you will need to install `srun` in the container, and that might not even be enough)